# Map two columns inside another table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a problem. I have two tables `table1` and `table2`. `table2` consist three columns and I would like to map two columns in my first `table1`.

```
# Table1
The first colum is some text, and the second are the headings
Name    ... ... Hours1  Hour2
1       ... ...
2       ... ...
3       ... ...
4       ... ...
```

```
# Table2
ID  Percentage      Hours
1   5%              6.5
2   10%             8.5
3   50%             4.5
```

What I want

```
Name    ... ... Hours1  Hour2
1       ... ...      5% 6.5
2       ... ...     10% 8.5
3       ... ...     50% 4.5
4       ... ...
```

I tried it with

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, table2!F:G, 2, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

*You may try these to pull `Percentage` & `Hours` in one go:*

```js
=xlookup(A2,Table2!A:A,Table2!B:C,)
```

OR

```js
=arrayformula(vlookup(A2,Table2!A:C,{2,3},))
```

- *Change ranges accordingly as `Table2!A:C` is assumed as the data range here*